# Dynamics CRM. Error oppening account after uninstalled managed solution

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

I have a managed solution with custom form on account. When I install it on my dev environment, go to account and switch to that new form and then uninstall the solution I can't open any account because CRM searches for that new form.

Is this something I'm doing wrong or this can be a bug in crm ?
If I import that solution again - I can open accounts.

If I switch to default form before deleting solution - this problem doesn't occur.

```
systemform With Id = 549c6a9e-e146-48cd-93fe-a178a29c256b Does Not Exist



    <InnerFault>
       <ErrorCode>-2147220969</ErrorCode>
       <ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
       <Message>systemform With Id = 549c6a9e-e146-48cd-93fe-a178a29c256b Does Not Exist</Message>
       <Timestamp>2016-04-26T18:29:01.1899408Z</Timestamp>
       <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
  </InnerFault>
```

Comment: CRM loads the last form you used, but it shouldn't be throwing an error if that form no longer exists.  In the scenario where you get the error, are you prevented from ever successfully opening an account again?  Side note: for questions that pertain to very specific errors, it would be helpful if you used the tag that pertains only to the CRM version where you got the error.  So if you get the error in CRM 2016, use the "dynamics-crm" and "dynamics-crm-2016" tags and leave off the other two.

Comment: If I import solution again or switch to default form before unistalling solution - error doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following: REMOVE ALL Internet Cache Files and Local Things. I Went Blind Folded and Cleared the Cache Manually and it WORKED!!:

1. Go to Folder: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer (Or Change to your user name folder)
2. Delete any cache folder, local cached data. These do not get deleted by the Delete using the Internet Explorer Options menu to Delete Browsing History. You MUST Delete the Local Cache
3. Close All Internet Explorer Browser Windows
4. Find ANY Locally Cached Data Files in these Folders:

brndlog.bak
brndlog.txt
DomainSuggestions
IECompatData
imagestore
Indexed DB
MSIMGSIZ.DAT
Pinned Sites
Recovery
TabRoaming
Tiles
Tracking Protection
UrlBlockManager
VersionManager

****BE SMART and CAREFUL *** Your Problem is in one of these above folders and look for data files that someone may be storing strange cookies or data for re-visiting their site (in this case dynamics crm)

**BY NOW: You should not see the error again (systemform With Id = GUID_OF_YOUR_FORM Does Not Exist)

When You See This Error or Similar (Guid Varies Per Your Environment):

Problem: systemform With Id = 1df14c99-6d3e-49b2-9f61-7c9870794d01 Does Not Exist